# Apache log file problem

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I've recently set up an Apache 2 web server and I noticed a quite a few lines in the error and access log that start with the follow sequence (but longer). Does anyone know where this comes from?

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ .......
```

My set up is an Apache 2 load balancer with mod_balancer enabled and two Apache 2 web servers.  All three servers write to the same log files on a share located on a NFS. My first guess is that my problem has to do with it since it's the only difference that comes to mind from other set ups I've used in the past but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence are just zero bytes. Such content of log files (not only those generated by Apache) is usually a result of a minor file system corruption caused by e.g. unclean system shutdown. As your files are stored on a network file system it probably may be caused by some kind of network outage.

Comment: I'm suspecting the NFS playing a role here. As far as I'm aware there have been no outages (I run my servers on Linode). The NFS is a separate server from the web servers and all are monitored by a dedicated monitor server (munin). I've rebooted my servers once but gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

are you using logrotation? this can happen when you rotate your logs without reloading apache.

Comment: With NFS it is quite possible, as the rotation could be done on a different machine that the one where Apache runse… Luke, is this the case?

Comment: Currently there is no log rotation set up. All web servers write into the same log file on an NFS share.